# Proof on property of convex and $\beta$-smooth function - missing term?

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am using this [set of notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4980.pdf). On page 268 it writes:

[image]

where \eqref{1} in the lemma is

> In particular this lemma shows that if $f$ is convex and $\beta$-smooth, then  for any $x,y \in \Bbb{R}^n$, one has
>   $$0 \le f(x) - f(y) - \nabla f(y)^\top (x - y) \le \frac\beta2 \lVert x -
>  y \rVert^2. \tag{3.4}\label1 $$
>
> My question is simple: are we missing a $\dfrac{\beta}{2}\|x - z\|^2$
>   term in the inequality in the encircled?

If not, is it because a function $f$ that satisfies \eqref{1} implies it is convex and $\beta$-smooth (i.e., $\Leftarrow$, note: this was not proved)?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the book's proof is alright.

## Explanation of the book's proof

Equation [$(3.4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611246/proof-on-property-of-convex-and-beta-smooth-function-missing-term#mjx-eqn-1) actually consists of two inequalities. $\require{action}$
\begin{align}
f(x) - f(y) &\ge \mathtip{\nabla f(y)^\top (x-y)}{f \text{ is convex}}
\tag1 \label{cvx}\\
f(x) - f(y) - \nabla f(y)^\top (x - y) &\le \mathtip{\frac\beta2 \lVert x -
 y \rVert^2}{\mbox{Lemma 3.4}} \tag2\label{lem34}
\end{align}

From the term $\dfrac{\beta}{2}\|z - y\|^2$ is the proof, it is obvious that \eqref{lem34} is applied to $f(z) - f(y)$, so that
$$ \mathtip{ f(z) - f(y) - \nabla f(y)^\top (z - y) \le \frac\beta2 \lVert z -
 y \rVert^2 }{x \leftarrow z, y \leftarrow y \text{ in } \eqref{lem34}} \tag3\label{lem35} $$
This gives
$$ f(z) - f(y) \le \nabla f(y)^\top (z - y) + \frac\beta2 \lVert z -
 y \rVert^2 \tag4\label{lem35b} $$
It remains to show
$$ f(x) - f(z) \le \nabla f(x)^\top (x - z). \tag5\label{lem35c}$$
It seems contradictory to \eqref{cvx}, but since \eqref{cvx} holds for *any* $x,y \in \Bbb{R}^n$, by multiplying $-1$ on both sides, \eqref{lem35c} is equivalent to
$$ \mathtip{f(z) - f(x) \ge \nabla f(x)^\top (z - x). \tag6\label{lem35d}}
{x \leftarrow z, y \leftarrow x \text{ in } \eqref{cvx}} $$
Add up \eqref{lem35b} and \eqref{lem35c} to give
\begin{align}
&\phantom{x=} f(x) - f(y) \\
&= f(x) - f(z) + f(z) - f(y) \\
&\le \mathtip{\nabla f(x)^\top (x - z)}{\text{inequality } \eqref{lem35c}} +
\mathtip{\nabla f(y)^\top (z - y) + \frac\beta2 \lVert z -
 y \rVert^2}{\text{inequality } \eqref{lem35b}}
\tag*{$\square$}
\end{align}

## Why the claimed missing term should *not* be used?

Since OP talks about $\dfrac{\beta}{2}\|x - z\|^2$, let me show you how we can mess up thing when we apply \eqref{lem34} on $f(x) - f(z)$ to get this term.
$$ f(x) - f(z) - \nabla f(z)^\top (x - z) \le \frac\beta2 \lVert x -
 z \rVert^2 \tag7\label{wrong} $$
Since $z:= y - \dfrac1\beta (\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x))$, $\nabla f(z)$ in \eqref{wrong} will become too complicated to be manipulated to give a meaningful result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but you lost me at "it remains to show". Why would equation (5) and (6) hold? They are clearly not derived from (1), since the variable evaluated at the gradient is different between (1) and (5),(6). I just can't see how (5) and (6) can be justified.

Comment: @ElCamino The logical flow is (1) = (6) ⟺ (5).

Comment: @ElCamino Sorry for the typo. (6) is just a change of label of (1).  I'll [mark this up with tool tip text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13259/290189).  Hover your mouse onto the inequality to test the visual effect.